# PHP library private classes

Tags: php, shared-libraries, private

How can I prevent users of a PHP library from using classes defined in the library which are not supposed to be used outside of it?

It would be nice if PHP had some concept of package or namespace visibility, so I could create private classes, but it doesn't.

The only thing I can think of is to put all the internal classes in a dedicated sub-namespace like `\Vendor\Project\_Internal\Class`, to make it obvious.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Why would you want that behaviour?

Comment: The same reason I do: have some classes that you can smash their signature down anytime you want, without being worried like "oh my, library's users may rely on that class, I cannot alter it!". I am looking for such thing: is there a PHPDoc annotation for that?